# $u_1+u_2+...+u_{2019}=0$, $u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_{2019}^2=1$. $a=\min\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{2019}\}$, $b=\max\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{2019}\}$. Prove $ab≤-\frac1{2019}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

> Let $u_1,u_2,...,u_{2019}$ be real numbers satisfying $u_1+u_2+...+u_{2019}=0$ and $u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_{2019}^2=1$. Let $a=\min\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{2019}\}$ and $b=\max\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{2019}\}$. Prove that $ab\le-\frac{1}{2019}$

Given that $u_1+u_2+...+u_{2019}=0,$

Squaring, $u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_{2019}^2+2$(sum of product of $u_i'$s taken two at a time)$=0$

So, sum of product of $u_i'$s taken two at a time=$-\frac{1}{2}$

I tried to take different values, but not able to satisfy all the three equations.

Maybe this question should be approached with some substitution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because $$0\geq\sum_{i=1}^{2019}(u_i-b)(u_i-a)=1+2019ab.$$

Answer (score 1):

I almost got there, but I just can't cross the finish line

---

For contest questions like this, it's often useful to look out for arbitrariness and symmetry. Looking at the question, $2019$ is an arbitrary value in the equations. But upon examination, there's nothing special about $2019$. So one can hypothesize that if the statement is supposed to be true for $2019$, it should also be true for any other $n$ used instead of $2019$.

One way to see this is using compact notation. Rephrasing the question with $n=2019$,

> Let $u_1,u_2,...,u_{n}$ be real numbers satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^2=1$. Let $a=\min_{1\leq i \leq n} u_i$ and $b=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} u_i$. Prove that $ab\le-\frac{1}{n}$

We have $a \leq u_i \leq b \; \forall i$. So,
\begin{align}
   0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} a = na \quad \Rightarrow \quad a \leq 0 \\
0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} b = nb \quad \Rightarrow \quad b \geq 0 \\
1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^2 = na^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad a^2 \leq \frac{1}{n} \\
1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} b^2 = nb^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad b^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

Combining the above four results, we get
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq a \leq 0 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq b$$

Now one might be tempted to multiply the first and third inequalities in the above to get to the result we need to prove. However, because the first inequality involves negative quantities, we can't simply multiply them together. To illustrate this, try to multiply $-3\leq-1$ and $1\leq2$, then apply the same method to multiply $-3\leq-1$ and $1\leq4$.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this approach could be completed to a solution (without using other ideas).